# php: Clean-up process remnants after user has canceled

Tags: php, process, stream, resource-cleanup

I have a page where I get the user to download data that the server zips right away for them. This is how it looks:

```
createFilesList(); //  <---- creates a text list of files do be zipped

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$downloadFilename.'');

$fp = popen('cat '.$fullListOfFiles.' | sudo -u myuser zip -@ -9 - ', 'r');

$bufsize = 8192;
$buff = '';
while( !feof($fp) ) 
{
    $buff = fread($fp, $bufsize);
    echo $buff;
}
pclose($fp);

doClean(); //  <----- deletes the list of files
```

**The problem**: If the user downloads the file, the clean-up works fine. However, if the user cancels the download, the list remains there uncleaned!

**Failed solution from other posts**: Other posts have suggested this solution:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

While this works fine to cleanup, it introduces a new problem: If the user cancels, the zipping process continues. This wastes resources on the computer for no good reason.

How can I guarantee that the clean-up runs?

Comment: Maybe  change your way how you do the cleanup or `register_shutdown_function` http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

Comment: @BrainFooLong Trying it! Thanks.

Comment: @BrainFooLong `register_shutdown_function()` works :) Post the answer so that I can accept it for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should run everytime, even after aborting by user -> `register_shutdown_function` http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

```
// register a shutdown cleanup
register_shutdown_function('doClean');

createFilesList(); //  <---- creates a text list of files do be zipped

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$downloadFilename.'');

$fp = popen('cat '.$fullListOfFiles.' | sudo -u myuser zip -@ -9 - ', 'r');

$bufsize = 8192;
$buff = '';
while( !feof($fp) ) 
{
    $buff = fread($fp, $bufsize);
    echo $buff;
}
pclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Never tried but maybe this could work : just use `connection_aborted()` to test before zipping.

```
createFilesList(); //  <---- creates a text list of files do be zipped

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$downloadFilename.'');

if(0 ==connection_aborted())
{
    $fp = popen('cat '.$fullListOfFiles.' | sudo -u myuser zip -@ -9 - ', 'r');

    $bufsize = 8192;
    $buff = '';
    while( !feof($fp) ) 
    {
        $buff = fread($fp, $bufsize);
        echo $buff;
    }
    pclose($fp);
}


doClean(); //  <----- deletes the list of files
```